# Variadic templates: Pass parameter pack without expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

The old C stdio facilities provided a way to pass along a variadic argument set using the `vprintf` facilities.

Is there a similar way to pass along a C++0x variadic template parameter pack *without* expanding it?

This might be useful if you have a derived class constructor that takes a variadic template parameter pack, and needs to simply pass it on to the base class constructor, rather than unpacking it.

For example:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
Base::Base(const T& v, const Args&... args) 
{
  /*...expand args here ....*/
}

template <class T, class... Args>
Derived::Derived(const T& v, const Args&... args) : Base(v, args)
{
  /*...don't expand args...*/
}
```

I thought you could simply pass around the `args` parameter pack without expanding it, by excluding the `...` after the args, but this simply results in a compiler error on GCC 4.3:

```
 error: parameter packs not expanded with `...'
```

So it is possible to pass along the parameter pack without expanding it?

Comment: As far as I know a C++0x parameter pack does not have a real existence on its own, its just a notation referring to the arguments. And as far as I know the only thing you can do with is expand it. Since that's at compile time, presumably it has no special overhead, and thus isn't a problem.

Comment: I think you need to put args... to pass them along.

Comment: haha, Thanks for the question, I was thinking to do the same but @Alf sir's comment opened my eyes :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand how expanding is an issue : won't expanded arguments be just *re-packed* in Base constructor ? I believe using `args...` will work as expected.